# Count a column of a resultant fetched table

Tags: mysql

I need to do a count of a column based on the resulted fetched table. I'm trying to combine it into 1 query instead of separating it.

The image that I have below provide better illustration. So assuming that I have 1000 records inside `PostTable`, and I want to retrieve the latest 20 records based on `PostTable.DateTime`. I have no issues with this.

But based on the resulted 20 records retrieved, I want to do a `COUNT` function to calculate the occurrence of how many times did `LikeID` occur with the existence of that `ImageID` found.

```
SELECT PostTable.PostID, PostTable.UserID, COUNT(LikeID), PostTable.DateTime 
FROM PostTable, LikeTable
WHERE PostTable.ImageID = LikeTable.ImageID
AND LikeTable.LikeID = ?????? // I'm stuck here
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group, so try this:

```
SELECT PostTable.PostID, PostTable.UserID, COUNT(LikeID) LikeCount, PostTable.DateTime 
FROM PostTable, LikeTable
WHERE PostTable.ImageID = LikeTable.ImageID
GROUP BY PostTable.PostID, PostTable.UserID, PostTable.DateTime
HAVING COUNT(LikeID) > 0
```

Read more on grouping: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html

Oh and consider looking into a more modern JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT pt.PostID, pt.UserID, COUNT(lt.LikeID) LikeCount, pt.DateTime 
FROM PostTable pt
LEFT JOIN LikeTable lt ON pt.ImageID = lt.ImageID -- Note it's a left join now
GROUP BY pt.PostID, pt.UserID, pt.DateTime
HAVING COUNT(lt.LikeID) > 0
```

@sagi ^^^ ;)

**Simplified example**

```
-- Two tables, a post can have many likes
CREATE TABLE post (postId INT);
CREATE TABLE `like` (postId INT);

-- Insert some posts and likes for some of those posts
INSERT INTO post VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8);
INSERT INTO `like` VALUES (1),(1),(3),(3),(5),(6),(7),(8);

-- Take a look at the data
SELECT * FROM post;
SELECT * FROM `like`;

-- Count the number of likes per post
SELECT p.postId, COUNT(l.postId) likes
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN `like` l ON p.postId = l.postId
GROUP BY p.postId
HAVING COUNT(l.postId) > 0; -- This removed the posts with no likes
```

Is that an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: When answering people you should always use EXPLICIT JOIN SYNTAX

Comment: Why should you use EJS when answering people? By that token, should I not use it in every day life?

Comment: Of course you should, I meant -especially- when answering people that don't know sql that good!

Comment: Well, I see statements of "fact" as a warning sign... If someone asks with an older syntax and you answer in a newer one, two things might happen: 1. They learn a "better" way of doing things. 2. You confuse them.

Comment: Thats why an expalantion of "You should use the proper syntax for joins" and maybe a link to it will be great.

Comment: Maybe. Put the question is about grouping. How many more things should we throw at him? :)

Comment: sorry, so do I ignore the portion on `-- AND LikeTable.LikeID = ?????? // I'm stuck here`??

Comment: it is only returning me rows with count value more than 0. I need the return of rows with count = 0. @sagi could you help me with this also?

Comment: its the same. it is still return me with rows that has count more than 0

Comment: Check the example at the bottom. Does that clear things up?

Comment: Yes. What you've done is exactly what I need. But i need to display all post regardless if there is likes or not. The problem here it is displaying only post with likes. Post with 0 likes are not displaying.

Comment: Then change the join from inner to left. I'm update the example.

Comment: your code does work! but not on mine. :( at least I have the structure now. will troubleshoot on mine. Thanks!

Comment: If I have a WHERE, after which line can I add in?